# (JAVA) How to convert a double from a list to an int

Tags: java, android, arraylist, int, double

I have made a list called `list` and two doubles called `Weight` and `Age`

Then I tried getting an element from the list like this `list.get((Age * 2) - 1)`, but it told me I can't put a double in the `get()` function, so I tried doing this `(int)(Age-1)` but when I put that chunk of code in an `if()` command like so
`if(list.get((int) ((Age * 2) - 1)) > Weight.intValue())`
but then for some reason, it gives me this exeption:

`operator ">" cannot be applied to "java.lang.Object","int"`

WHY, JUST WHY!

in total, here is my code (Note that I wrote it with some extra android libraries)

```
package com.example.ademapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Weight);
            EditText text3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Age);
            Double Weight = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
            EditText text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Height);
            Double Height = Double.parseDouble(text2.getText().toString());
            Double IMC = Weight/Height/Math.pow(Height/100,2);
            TextView Result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
            List list = Arrays.asList(15,19,14.5,16.5,14,16,13.75,17.5,13.5,17.5,13,17.5,13,18,13,18.5,13.25,19,13.5,20,13.75,20.5,14,21,14.5,22,15,22.5,15.5,23,16,24,16.5,24.5,17,25);
            Double Age = Double.parseDouble(text3.getText().toString());
            RadioButton Adult = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Adult);
            RadioButton Kid = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Kid);
            if(Adult.isChecked())
            {
                if (IMC<18.5)
                {
                    Result.setText("Tu est Trop Maigre!");
                }
                else if (IMC>30)
                {
                    Result.setText("Tu est Trop Gras!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Result.setText("Bravo! Tu est en bonne santée!");
                }
            }
            else if (Kid.isChecked())
            {

                if(list.get((int) ((Age * 2) - 1)) > Weight.intValue())
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3890632)

Comment: So much extra code. Post only the minimum needed to demonstrate your particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use not generic list.

```
 List list = Arrays.asList(15,19, ... , 25)
```

If the list is not generic, it contains Objects.(the most common class in java)
You store ints and doubles together so you need to generic it by their parent

```
List<? extends Number> list = Arrays.asList(15,19, ... , 25)
```

and then take its double value, while you can't cast double to int, but it's ok to cast int to double

```
if(list.get((int) ((Age * 2) - 1)).doubleValue() > Weight.intValue())
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Declare the type of your list’s content with `<Double>`.

```java
List < Double > inputDoubles = List.of( 15,19,14.5,16.5,14,16,13.75,17.5,13.5,17.5,13,17.5,13,18,13,18.5,13.25,19,13.5,20,13.75,20.5,14,21,14.5,22,15,22.5,15.5,23,16,24,16.5,24.5,17,25 ) ;
```

## Use generics

As khelwood commented, see: [*What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3890632).

Use the [generics feature of Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), where you specify the data type to be held by your `List` collection. Without specifying the type to be held, `< Double >`, the list has no idea of the type of a retrieved element.

Without generics, when you call `list.get( … )` the compiler sees only an [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) object rather than a [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html) object. Your code `> Weight.intValue()` is asking to compare an `Object` object to a `int` primitive which makes no sense because an `Object` object is not a number.

Instead of this:

```
List list = Arrays.asList(15,19,14.5,16.5,14,16,13.75,17.5,13.5,17.5,13,17.5,13,18,13,18.5,13.25,19,13.5,20,13.75,20.5,14,21,14.5,22,15,22.5,15.5,23,16,24,16.5,24.5,17,25);
```

…add `< Double >` to your `List` declaration, like this:

```
List < Double > list = Arrays.asList(15,19,14.5,16.5,14,16,13.75,17.5,13.5,17.5,13,17.5,13,18,13,18.5,13.25,19,13.5,20,13.75,20.5,14,21,14.5,22,15,22.5,15.5,23,16,24,16.5,24.5,17,25);
```

You have just told the compiler that this particular [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) object is a list of [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html) objects. Code that puts a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), `Dog`, or `Invoice` object into that list will not compile. Conversely, when retrieving an element from the list, the compiler knows for sure the retrieved element is the correct expected type, a `Double`. So no [casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) needed.

And, by the way, we now have a more convenient literals syntax using [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)). The result is a [non-modifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).

And generally best to use more descriptive names on your variables, such as `inputDoubles` rather than `list`.

```
List < Double > inputDoubles = List.of( 15,19,14.5,16.5,14,16,13.75,17.5,13.5,17.5,13,17.5,13,18,13,18.5,13.25,19,13.5,20,13.75,20.5,14,21,14.5,22,15,22.5,15.5,23,16,24,16.5,24.5,17,25 ) ;
```